# Send different mail content to the recipients in the same mail via outlook addin

Tags: c#, email, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

Can we send the the different mail content to the recipients in same mail by using outlook addin or any other way?

for example if i send the mail to the customer "a" along with other customers
the text "hai a" should be added in the mail but only the customer "a" should  see that message and other recipients in the same mail should not see the "hai a" content

is this possible?

i am using outlook 2010 and VSTO

Comment: BCC sounds like an option however.. I would personally generate 2 different emails create 2 different email groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must send separate emails if you want different recipients to see different content.